# Sonic the hedgehog style boost pads in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way using command blocks or plugins to alter a player's momentum (xyz) when they step on a pressure plate? /entitydata works for mobs, but unfortunately it does not affect players.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to help you, but on servers, I think they achieve this using plugins.

Comment: @DorianDore I believe I've seen a singleplayer unmodded (not entirely sure about the 'vanilla-ness' though) parkour map where a player was launched into the air after stepping on a platform.

Comment: I've seen it done with speed potion spawners under the floor.

Answer (score 1):

Use /entitydata to modify the motion tag of the entitiy:

```
/entitydata @e {Motion:[X,Y,Z]}
```

Note the XYZ is in double format, example:

```
/entitydata @e {Motion:[0.0,1.0,0.0]}
```

Comment: works for entities, but unfortunately not for players. broadening question a bit for plugins

Answer (score -1):

Use a command block with the command:

```
/effect @p minecraft:speed [duration] [level]
```

This adds a speed effect to the nearest player (so it would be best to play the command block directly under the pressure plate)

Duration is in seconds, level is the increase in speed (each level adds 20% speed, so level 5 is double speed)

Comment: Generally it's best to explain your answer in more detail than simply posting a command, lots of people wouldn't know what to do with it. (Also, I think he want the play to be more, pushed in a direction, than given a speed boost)